# Comparing hash of hashes in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am having two structures similar to the one below.

```
[1 => [{'pc'=>1,'id'=>0},{'pc'=>4,'id'=>0},{'pc'=>2,'id'=>1]]
```

But both of them need not contain the inside array in the exact same order. How to compare in such case?

Comment: Consider converting the Arrays to Sets first, then the order doesn't matter.

Comment: Do you need to consider duplicates within the lists?

Answer (score 1):

If the order isn't important, you should consider other structures instead of Array there, [`Set`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Set), for example.

You can use Set for comparing as well, by converting Arrays to Sets before comparison:

```
require 'set'
a = [{:a => 2}, {:b => 3}]
b = [{:b => 3}, {:a => 2}]

sa = Set.new a
#=> #<Set: {{:a=>2}, {:b=>3}}>
sb = Set.new b
#=> #<Set: {{:b=>3}, {:a=>2}}>

a == b
#=> false
sa == sb
#=> true
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems a simple compare works:

```
data = {
  1 => [{'pc'=>1,'id'=>0},{'pc'=>4,'id'=>0},{'pc'=>2,'id'=>1}],
  2 => [{'pc'=>1,'id'=>0},{'pc'=>4,'id'=>0},{'pc'=>2,'id'=>1}],
  3 => [{'pc'=>1,'id'=>0},{'pc'=>2,'id'=>1},{'pc'=>4,'id'=>0}]
}
data[1] == data[2]
#> true
data[2] == data[3]
#> false
```

Answer (score 0):

If both the nested hashes having same keys & order, we can write a recursive method to do the comparison. I am not sure whether we have inbuilt method to do so.